# jQuery ui Autocomplete suggestions OverLaping in IE-6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, bgiframe

I am working with [jQuery ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) v.18.16 and jQuery v1.7. It is working fine in all browsers except IE 6. Below AutoComplete TextBox, I have combo boxes. These combo box vales are overlapping the auto suggestions. I tried the bgiframe plugin but still have the problem. The example is http://ksrtc.in/site/jq1/. Try it with `From` places like "ban", "man".

Answer (score 0):

IE 6 is dead.. or it should be.

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try calling the bgiframe function manually instead of having jQuery do it and see if that works?

Comment: i am calling manually, i placed separated bgiframe in my libs and giving that path in my page. is i have call on particular id?

Comment: @hari -- yes, in addition to including the script file. you have to call the bgiframe function. if you look in the jqueryui source, it calls the bgiframe function for you if it exists.